# Japanese Kanji not authorized on Worldbuilding?

Tags: bug, special-characters

When composing [that answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/23827/9685) on Worldbuilding, I wanted to give an example in Japanese. I used the typical canna input method.

As can be seen, hiragana and katakana were accepted without problems, but I wanted to write "China", and a red sign appeared saying that (paraphrasing)

> It is not allowed to use the *[naka](http://thejapanesepage.com/kanji/%E4%B8%AD)-character* in the body of a post.

I replaced China with Japan, but had the same remark about the [first Kanji for Japan](http://thejapanesepage.com/kanji/%E6%97%A5). I suppressed all kanjis and I got no complain, not even when clicking "Post".

Is there any reason for that or was that a bug, or should I have ignore that message and try to force the post anyway?

Comment: SE is getting huge amounts of spam with some character sets, so they block all contents having those characters to prevent the spam flood.